# What's the name for the phenomenon of hating attitudes similar but not identical to your own?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a thing where people will tend to hate those that almost agree with them more than they hate the ones that completely disagree with them. Is there a term for this? Has it been studied?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Can you provide a little more context?  What led you to believe "there's [such] a thing?"  Can you give an example of this phenomenon?

Comment: I suppose I’d be more ***frustrated*** with someone who was so close to agreeing with me but wouldn’t than with someone whom I viewed as a lost cause from the start.

Comment: 'Almost agree' is very open to interpretation. Who decides on the degree of difference? Thin ends of wedges come to mind.

Answer (score 5):

The term (although not a single word) is *the narcissism of small differences*.

There's a Wikipedia article about it:

> The narcissism of small differences (German: der Narzissmus der
>   kleinen Differenzen) is the thesis that it is precisely communities
>   with adjoining territories and close relationships that engage in
>   constant feuds and mutual ridicule because of hypersensitivity to
>   details of differentiation.[1] The term was coined by Sigmund Freud in
>   1917, based on the earlier work of British anthropologist Ernest
>   Crawley. In language differing only slightly from current
>   psychoanalytic terminology, Crawley declared that each individual is
>   separated from others by a taboo of personal isolation, a narcissism
>   of minor differences.

Answer (score 3):

"[Sectarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectarianism)."

> Sectarianism is a form of bigotry, discrimination, or hatred arising
>   from attaching relations of inferiority and superiority to differences
>   between subdivisions within a group. Common examples are denominations
>   of a religion, ethnic identity, class, or region for citizens of a
>   state and factions of a political movement.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could use the law of attraction to describe this phenomenon.

> Like poles repel each other while unlike poles attract.

It may not have widespread acceptance but I find it conveys the message well enough (with visual imagery of like poles of a magnet repelling each other)